# In SSRS, is it possible to make a context sensitive report containing multiple subreports for dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have designed a SSRS report having multiple sub-reports. The report is working fine but displaying data for all records.
But my need is to make it context sensitive.

Below is the query for the main report.

```
SELECT Filterednew_franchisee.new_franchiseeid, 
  Filterednew_franchisee.new_name, 
  Filterednew_monthlypayment.new_insurance
FROM Filterednew_franchisee 
INNER JOIN Filterednew_monthlypayment 
ON Filterednew_franchisee.new_franchiseeid = 
  Filterednew_monthlypayment.new_franchiseeid
WHERE (Filterednew_monthlypayment.new_yearmonth = 
  @reportyear + @reportmonth) 
AND (Filterednew_franchisee.new_franchiseeid IN 
  (select new_franchiseeid 
    from Filterednew_franchisee as CRMAF_Filterednew_franchisee))
```

Sub-reports are using the fields from the above query as parameter.

Am I missing something ? Is there any other approach that needs to be followed?  Is it really possible to design a context sensitive report having multiple sub-reports?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, context-sensitive reports are possible. The name `Filtered` as in `Filterednew_franchisee` refers to a SQL Server view that is designed for the sake of security roles. To gain access to context-sensitive views, [the API takes an arbitrary prefix called `CRMAF_` and translates it into a context-sensitive query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328288.aspx#SQLBasedPre_Filtering).

Thankfully, the [SDK includes a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334242.aspx) view (which I've copied below).

```sql
SELECT 
    CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecodename as activitytypecodename,
    CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.regardingobjectidname as regardingobjectidname,
    CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.subject as subject,
    CRMAF_FilteredAccount.name
FROM FilteredActivityPointer AS CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer
    INNER JOIN FilteredAccount As CRMAF_FilteredAccount on
        CRMAF_FilteredAccount.accountid =
        CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.regardingobjectid
```

Comment: Peter, I have tried it in same way. But didn't work. Still showing my reports under "Run for all records". Just for your info, I have done other reports in same way as you have mentioned are working fine and also appeared under "Run for Selected Records".